# Generate a sequence number in xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to get a sequence number in the output of the xml using xslt 1.0.

```
`<a>  
 <b>  
<c>   
  <d>text1</d>  
  </c>  
  <c>  
    <d>text2</d>  
    </c>  
    </b>  
    <b>  
      <c>  
        <d>text3</d>  
        </c>  
        <c>  
          <d>text4</d>  
          </c>  
    </b>  
</a>`
```

The output xml should be like

```
`  <result>  
    <seq>1</seq>    
    <r>text1</r>  
    <seq>2</seq>  
    <r>text2</r>  
    <seq>3</seq>  
    <r>text3</r>  
    <seq>4</seq>  
    <r>text4</r>  
  </result>  `.
```

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `xsl:number level="any"`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="a">
  <result>
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//d"/>
  </result>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="d">
  <seq><xsl:number level="any"/></seq>
  <r><xsl:value-of select="."/></r>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <result>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//d"/>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="d">
    <seq>
        <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
    </seq>
    <r>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </r>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: position() can be used