# Group by specific value and generate sequence number using xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to generate a holiday plan based on multiple travels as a travel agency can offer. So, I have multiple travels that I must link (based on travel agency) and generate a sequence number for each location I visit (including start and end location per day). Thank you!
e.g: 2 travels from one agency

Travel day1:

- 1 - start location (agency place)
- 2 - objective 1
- 3 - objective 2
- 4 - end location (hotel)

Travel day2:

- 1 - start location (hotel)
- 2 - objective 3
- 3 - end location (hotel)

Travel day3:

- 1 - start location (hotel)
- 2 - end location (agency place)

From this 3 travels I would like to get one single travel like this:

Travel 1:

- 1 - start location (agency place)
- 2 - objective 1
- 3 - objective 2
- 4 - end location (hotel) / start location from travel day2 (it is the same that's why I need to add it just once)
- 5 - objective 3
- 6 - end location (hotel) / start location from travel day3 (it is the same that's why I need to add it just once)
- 7 - end location (agency place)

Input xml:

```
<HolidayPlan>
    <!-- first holiday -->
    <Travel>
        <UniqueTravelID>100-1</UniqueTravelID>
        <TravelAgency>Agency1</TravelAgency>
        <StartLocationID>A</StartLocationID>
        <EndLocationID>B</EndLocationID>
        <Day>1</Day>
        <IntermediateObjectives>
            <Objective1>
                <UniqueObjectiveID>Objective1</UniqueObjectiveID>
                <ObjectiveNumber>1</ObjectiveNumber>
            </Objective1>
            <Objective2>
                <UniqueObjectiveID>Objective2</UniqueObjectiveID>
                <ObjectiveNumber>2</ObjectiveNumber>
            </Objective2>
        </IntermediateObjectives>
    </Travel>
    <Travel>
        <UniqueTravelID>100-1</UniqueTravelID>
        <TravelAgency>Agency1</TravelAgency>
        <StartLocationID>B</StartLocationID>
        <EndLocationID>B</EndLocationID>
        <Day>2</Day>
        <IntermediateObjectives>
            <Objective1>
                <UniqueObjectiveID>Objective3</UniqueObjectiveID>
                <ObjectiveNumber>1</ObjectiveNumber>
            </Objective1>
        </IntermediateObjectives>
    </Travel>
    <Travel>
        <UniqueTravelID>100-3</UniqueTravelID>
        <TravelAgency>Agency1</TravelAgency>
        <StartLocationID>B</StartLocationID>
        <EndLocationID>A</EndLocationID>
        <Day>3</Day>
        <IntermediateObjectives>
        </IntermediateObjectives>
    </Travel>

    <!-- second holiday -->
    <Travel>
        <UniqueTravelID>200-1</UniqueTravelID>
        <TravelAgency>Agency2</TravelAgency>
        <StartLocationID>C</StartLocationID>
        <EndLocationID>D</EndLocationID>
        <Day>1</Day>
        <IntermediateObjectives>
            <Objective1>
                <UniqueObjectiveID>Objective1</UniqueObjectiveID>
                <ObjectiveNumber>1</ObjectiveNumber>
            </Objective1>
        </IntermediateObjectives>
    </Travel>
    <Travel>
        <UniqueTravelID>200-2</UniqueTravelID>
        <TravelAgency>Agency2</TravelAgency>
        <StartLocationID>D</StartLocationID>
        <EndLocationID>C</EndLocationID>
        <Day>2</Day>
        <IntermediateObjectives>
        </IntermediateObjectives>
    </Travel>
</HolidayPlan>
```

Expected result:

```
<VisitedPlaces>
    <Place>
        <UniqueTravelID>100-1</UniqueTravelID>
        <TravelAgency>Agency1</TravelAgency>
        <UniqueObjectiveID>A</UniqueObjectiveID>
        <ObjectiveNumber>1</ObjectiveNumber>
    </Place>
    <Place>
        <UniqueTravelID>100-1</UniqueTravelID>
        <TravelAgency>Agency1</TravelAgency>
        <UniqueObjectiveID>Objective1</UniqueObjectiveID>
        <ObjectiveNumber>2</ObjectiveNumber>
    </Place>
    <Place>
        <UniqueTravelID>100-1</UniqueTravelID>
        <TravelAgency>Agency1</TravelAgency>
        <UniqueObjectiveID>Objective2</UniqueObjectiveID>
        <ObjectiveNumber>3</ObjectiveNumber>
    </Place>
        <Place>
        <UniqueTravelID>100-1</UniqueTravelID>
        <TravelAgency>Agency1</TravelAgency>
        <UniqueObjectiveID>B</UniqueObjectiveID>
        <ObjectiveNumber>4</ObjectiveNumber>
    </Place>
    <Place>
        <UniqueTravelID>100-1</UniqueTravelID>
        <TravelAgency>Agency1</TravelAgency>
        <UniqueObjectiveID>Objective3</UniqueObjectiveID>
        <ObjectiveNumber>5</ObjectiveNumber>
    </Place>
    <Place>
        <UniqueTravelID>100-1</UniqueTravelID>
        <TravelAgency>Agency1</TravelAgency>
        <UniqueObjectiveID>B</UniqueObjectiveID>
        <ObjectiveNumber>6</ObjectiveNumber>
    </Place>
    <Place>
        <UniqueTravelID>100-1</UniqueTravelID>
        <TravelAgency>Agency1</TravelAgency>
        <UniqueObjectiveID>A</UniqueObjectiveID>
        <ObjectiveNumber>7</ObjectiveNumber>
    </Place>

    <Place>
        <UniqueTravelID>200-1</UniqueTravelID>
        <TravelAgency>Agency2</TravelAgency>
        <UniqueObjectiveID>C</UniqueObjectiveID>
        <ObjectiveNumber>1</ObjectiveNumber>
    </Place>
    <Place>
        <UniqueTravelID>200-1</UniqueTravelID>
        <TravelAgency>Agency2</TravelAgency>
        <UniqueObjectiveID>Objerctive1</UniqueObjectiveID>
        <ObjectiveNumber>2</ObjectiveNumber>
    </Place>
    <Place>
        <UniqueTravelID>200-1</UniqueTravelID>
        <TravelAgency>Agency2</TravelAgency>
        <UniqueObjectiveID>D</UniqueObjectiveID>
        <ObjectiveNumber>3</ObjectiveNumber>
    </Place>
        <Place>
        <UniqueTravelID>200-1</UniqueTravelID>
        <TravelAgency>Agency2</TravelAgency>
        <UniqueObjectiveID>C</UniqueObjectiveID>
        <ObjectiveNumber>4</ObjectiveNumber>
    </Place>
</VisitedPlaces>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate a sequence number in xslt 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21510246/generate-a-sequence-number-in-xslt-1-0)

Comment: My case is different because I'm also trying to group by the value of one specific tag.

Comment: Google (or search in Stack Overflow) for "Muenchian grouping"; that's the most widely used technique for solving this kind of grouping problem in 1.0.

Comment: @user9068296 Please see my answer below, hope it will help.

Comment: Hello, Thank you very much for your answer! It is very useful for me. Sorry for my delayed answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was creating template for **Place** structure as first stage to make code more clear, then template for creating structure per **TravelAgency** and pass them in main template with duplicates preventing, please see XSL below (*with some explanation in comments*):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"> 
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <!--create Place structure-->
    <xsl:template name="place">
        <xsl:param name="param.travel.id"/>
        <xsl:param name="param.travel.agency"/> 
        <xsl:param name="param.object.id"/>
        <xsl:param name="param.object.number"/>  
        <Place>                
            <UniqueTravelID>                    
                <xsl:value-of select="$param.travel.id"/>                
            </UniqueTravelID>                
            <TravelAgency>                    
                <xsl:value-of select="$param.travel.agency"/>                
            </TravelAgency>                
            <UniqueObjectiveID>                    
                <xsl:value-of select="$param.object.id"/>                                    
            </UniqueObjectiveID>                
            <ObjectiveNumber>                    
                <xsl:value-of select="$param.object.number"/>                
            </ObjectiveNumber>            
        </Place>        
    </xsl:template>    
    <!--create template with Place filter by Agency--> 
    <xsl:template name="filter-place">
        <xsl:param name="param.agency"/>   
        <xsl:for-each select="/HolidayPlan/Travel[TravelAgency = $param.agency]">
            <xsl:variable name="var.travel.id" select="/HolidayPlan/Travel[TravelAgency = $param.agency][1]/UniqueTravelID"/>
            <xsl:variable name="var.travel.agency" select="/HolidayPlan/Travel[TravelAgency = $param.agency][1]/TravelAgency"/>
            <xsl:variable name="var.prev.obj.count" select="count(preceding::Travel[TravelAgency = $param.agency]/IntermediateObjectives//UniqueObjectiveID[1])"/>                      
            <xsl:variable name="var.object.number" select="position() + $var.prev.obj.count"/>
            <!--create day counter from Day-->
            <xsl:variable name="var.day">                    
                <xsl:choose>                        
                    <xsl:when test="normalize-space(Day) = '1'">                            
                        <xsl:value-of select="Day"/>                        
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Day + $var.prev.obj.count"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>                
            </xsl:variable>    
            <!--apply Place structure from Travel-->
            <xsl:call-template name="place">
                <xsl:with-param name="param.travel.id" select="$var.travel.id"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="param.travel.agency" select="$var.travel.agency"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="param.object.id" select="StartLocationID"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="param.object.number" select="$var.day"/>    
            </xsl:call-template>
            <!--apply Place structure from IntermediateObjectives-->            
            <xsl:if test="IntermediateObjectives/*">
                <xsl:for-each select="IntermediateObjectives/*">
                        <xsl:call-template name="place">
                            <xsl:with-param name="param.travel.id" select="$var.travel.id"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="param.travel.agency" select="$var.travel.agency"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="param.object.id" select="./UniqueObjectiveID"/>
                            <!--Day counter from IntermediateObjectives-->
                            <xsl:with-param name="param.object.number" select="$var.day + ./ObjectiveNumber"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>               
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!--create counter variables for last day-->
        <xsl:variable name="travel.count" select="count(/HolidayPlan/Travel[TravelAgency = $param.agency])" />
        <xsl:variable name="all.obj.count" select="count(/HolidayPlan/Travel[TravelAgency = $param.agency]/IntermediateObjectives/*/UniqueObjectiveID)" /> 
        <!--apply Place structure for last day-->                                       
        <xsl:call-template name="place">
            <xsl:with-param name="param.travel.id" select="/HolidayPlan/Travel[TravelAgency = $param.agency][1]/UniqueTravelID"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="param.travel.agency" select="/HolidayPlan/Travel[TravelAgency = $param.agency][1]/TravelAgency"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="param.object.id" select="/HolidayPlan/Travel[TravelAgency = $param.agency][position() = $travel.count]/EndLocationID"/>
            <!--calculation last counter as next Travel Days + Intermediate Objectives + First Day-->
            <xsl:with-param name="param.object.number" select="$travel.count + $all.obj.count + 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>                                         
    </xsl:template>
    <!--main template - VisitedPlaces structure-->
    <xsl:template match="/"> 
        <VisitedPlaces>                                                               
            <xsl:for-each select="/HolidayPlan/Travel">
                <!--preventing TravelAgency values duplicates and pass to filter-place template as parameter-->            
                <xsl:if test="not(preceding::Travel[TravelAgency/text() = current()/TravelAgency/text()])">                                                    
                    <xsl:call-template name="filter-place">                                            
                        <xsl:with-param name="param.agency" select="./TravelAgency"/>                                    
                    </xsl:call-template>                          
                </xsl:if>                 
            </xsl:for-each>
        </VisitedPlaces>         
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And result as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<VisitedPlaces>
    <Place>
        <UniqueTravelID>100-1</UniqueTravelID>
        <TravelAgency>Agency1</TravelAgency>
        <UniqueObjectiveID>A</UniqueObjectiveID>
        <ObjectiveNumber>1</ObjectiveNumber>
    </Place>
    <Place>
        <UniqueTravelID>100-1</UniqueTravelID>
        <TravelAgency>Agency1</TravelAgency>
        <UniqueObjectiveID>Objective1</UniqueObjectiveID>
        <ObjectiveNumber>2</ObjectiveNumber>
    </Place>
    <Place>
        <UniqueTravelID>100-1</UniqueTravelID>
        <TravelAgency>Agency1</TravelAgency>
        <UniqueObjectiveID>Objective2</UniqueObjectiveID>
        <ObjectiveNumber>3</ObjectiveNumber>
    </Place>
    <Place>
        <UniqueTravelID>100-1</UniqueTravelID>
        <TravelAgency>Agency1</TravelAgency>
        <UniqueObjectiveID>B</UniqueObjectiveID>
        <ObjectiveNumber>4</ObjectiveNumber>
    </Place>
    <Place>
        <UniqueTravelID>100-1</UniqueTravelID>
        <TravelAgency>Agency1</TravelAgency>
        <UniqueObjectiveID>Objective3</UniqueObjectiveID>
        <ObjectiveNumber>5</ObjectiveNumber>
    </Place>
    <Place>
        <UniqueTravelID>100-1</UniqueTravelID>
        <TravelAgency>Agency1</TravelAgency>
        <UniqueObjectiveID>B</UniqueObjectiveID>
        <ObjectiveNumber>6</ObjectiveNumber>
    </Place>
    <Place>
        <UniqueTravelID>100-1</UniqueTravelID>
        <TravelAgency>Agency1</TravelAgency>
        <UniqueObjectiveID>A</UniqueObjectiveID>
        <ObjectiveNumber>7</ObjectiveNumber>
    </Place>
    <Place>
        <UniqueTravelID>200-1</UniqueTravelID>
        <TravelAgency>Agency2</TravelAgency>
        <UniqueObjectiveID>C</UniqueObjectiveID>
        <ObjectiveNumber>1</ObjectiveNumber>
    </Place>
    <Place>
        <UniqueTravelID>200-1</UniqueTravelID>
        <TravelAgency>Agency2</TravelAgency>
        <UniqueObjectiveID>Objective1</UniqueObjectiveID>
        <ObjectiveNumber>2</ObjectiveNumber>
    </Place>
    <Place>
        <UniqueTravelID>200-1</UniqueTravelID>
        <TravelAgency>Agency2</TravelAgency>
        <UniqueObjectiveID>D</UniqueObjectiveID>
        <ObjectiveNumber>3</ObjectiveNumber>
    </Place>
    <Place>
        <UniqueTravelID>200-1</UniqueTravelID>
        <TravelAgency>Agency2</TravelAgency>
        <UniqueObjectiveID>C</UniqueObjectiveID>
        <ObjectiveNumber>4</ObjectiveNumber>
    </Place>
</VisitedPlaces>
```

Hope it will help with your case.